# Google cloud CDN with Cloud run as origin

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-cdn

I noticed that Cloud CDN added custom origin as an option: https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/custom-origins-overview

Does this mean that we can finally use GCP server-less offerings (app engine, cloud run) as an origin for their load balancer / CDN?

Has anyone tried it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation you shared, the Cloud CDN Custom Origin is intended to provide content hosted in another cloud (on-premises) and must be outside of the Google Cloud.
The Cloud CDN in use of HTTP(S) Load Balancer can be sourced for the following backends: Instance Groups, Zonal NEGs, Internet NEGs and Backend Buckets [1](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/custom-origins-overview#supported-origins). Which the Internet NEGs relies on as a non-GCP service.
“Internet NEGs are also known as custom origins. Internet NEGs can be origins hosted within an on-premises infrastructure or origins provided by third-party providers.”

Let’s say that it is not compatible with App Engine or Cloud Run in GCP services.